# Postfix - E-mails missing, no message in the log

Tags: debian, postfix, logging, dovecot

I'm setting up a `postfix` + `dovecot` mail server for myself on a VPS. I plan to host a couple of domains with it and be able to manage the users via MySQL.

It currently works as I would like to but it misses e-mails sent from some hosts. When that happens, there is nothing on the logs. So I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why this is happening, anything that could point me out in the right direction is highly appreciated.

These are some of the tests I did so far:

- Sending from Gmail to user@mydomain.com: Works - Appears in logs
- Sending mails from user@mydomain.com to anywhere: Works - Appears in logs
- Sendings from Github to user@mydomain.com: Doesn't work - Nothing in the logs

(Same happens with several hosts)

Here are the contents of my `postfix/master.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = mydomain.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.net, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /srv/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_alias_domains =

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
command_directory = /usr/sbin
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

message_size_limit = 30720000

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

And in the VPS: Debian Wheezy, Postfix 2.9.6, Dovecot 2.1.7
```

I will keep trying to figure out why or at least to get something logged and update the post.

Comment: Your config shows some obvious problems related to your apparent obfuscation. I assume, of course, that you don't actually own mydomain.com. Please see [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. What problems do you find obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might have a problem with your MX records. You may want to validate them with something like mxtoolbox.com to ensure they show up right. Take a look at the headers of one of the successful messages too. Frequently you can find hints of problems there.

Comment: It was a propagation related issue so I will mark this as the correct answer. Thanks !